# Как включить поддержку ads111x в Raspberry PI?

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, ads

хочу использовать библиотеку для C++ libiio для взаимодействия с ацп ADS1115 на raspberry pi. Библиотека использует официальный драйвер оболочки ядра linux для общения с семейством подобных ацп, в том числе и с ADS1115. Вопрос как его активировать?(i2c включен: отредактировал boot/config.txt, проверил что все работает i2cdetect - показывает адрес 48, как и должно быть). Пробовал следующее:

1. Вписывал в boot/config.txt строчку device ads111x
2. На всякий случай по какому-то отрытому совету вставлял dtoverlay=i2c-dev в boot/config.txt

Почему я считаю что он уже не включен? Утилита iio_info идущая парой с библиотекой libiio показывает сообщение:

```
    Library version: 0.23 (git tag: v0.23)
    Compiled with backends: local xml ip usb
    Unable to create Local IIO context : No such file or directory (2)
```

Помимо этого при попытке запустить простой пример(код ниже) летит исключение практически сразу:

```
#include <iio.h>

int main(void)
{
    iio_context* iio_context_ = iio_create_default_context();
    if (iio_context_get_devices_count(iio_context_) <= 0) {  // exception here
        return -1;
    }
return 1;
}
```

В гугле решения не нашел, в принципе очень мало информации по драйверу этому, не понимаю почему, вроде бы официальная штука..

Comment: https://ez.analog.com/linux-software-drivers/f/q-a/537335/libiio-for-raspbian-buster, но нужен vpn (tor не пойдёт)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, я не правильно редактировал boot/config.txt.
Вместо: строчки `device ads111x` в boot/config.txt надо вписать `dtoverlay=ads1115`.

В общем, кто хочет поработать с этим драйвером общий алгоритм такой:

1. Установить библиотеку libiio `sudo apt install libiio-dev`
2. Установить утилиты для работы с ней `sudo apt install libiio-utils`
3. Включить нужный интерфейс по которому подключено устройство: i2c, spi итд(в интернете полно гайдов как это сделать).
4. Вписать в файл boot/config.txt строчку `dtoverlay=ads1115` и перезагрузить
5. Проверить с помощью утилиты iio_info что все правильно установилось. Если всё ок, то она выдаст список доступных устройств и список доступных каналов

Comment: Было бы еще интересно узнать, за что отвечает `dtoverlay` и почему туда необходимо вписывать магическое число 1115. В [иных местах](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/master/boot/overlays/README) пишут что необходимо писать `dtoverlay=ads1115`.

Comment: @user7860670, магическое число 1115 - это моя ошибка, я поправил